# Probability generating functions

Tags: probability

Let $X$ have probability generating function $G_X(s)$ and let $u_n=\mathbb{P}(X>n)$. How do I show that the genrating function $U(s)$ of the sequence $u_0,u_1,...$ satisfies $(1-s)U(s)=1-G_X(s)$, whenever the series defining these generating functions converge? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$U\left(s\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_{n}s^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}p_{k}s^{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}p_{k}s^{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p_{k}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}s^{n}$$

leading to:

$$\left(1-s\right)U\left(s\right)==\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p_{k}\left(1-s^{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p_{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p_{k}s^{k}=1-G_{X}\left(s\right)$$

Comment: How did you get the last line $(1-s)U(s)==...$? Hopefully you're still here...

Comment: $(1-s)(1+\cdots+s^{k-1})=(1+\cdots+s^{k-1})-(s+\cdots+s^k)=1-s^k$